# jQuery UI nested list

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I am having an issue in trying to get the 2 product ul items to sit within the first tab, they are always outside the tab

if i remove the:

```
float: left
```

from the

```
.featured-products-grid li.item { float:left; width:132px; padding:25px 5px 30px; }
```

thin it works, but the products are not aligned horizontally.

here is the page

http://khine.3b1.org/jquery/product.html

what am i missing

Comment: Please paste the relevant code here so that it will help others even if the page goes down.

Comment: sorry, i will in future paste the code as well, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to [clear your floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html). If you add the following style to `ul.featured-products-grid` you should be good:

```css
ul.featured-products-grid {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```